# FFmpeg library: Muxing audio from external file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have successfully changed the muxing.c sample to use video frames that I generate on runtime.

I am trying now to replace the `get_audio_frame` function with a function that decodes an existing audio file, and writes its samples instead of the synthesized audio-samples in the example code.

I've tried using the "audio decoding" example to decode the audio file, but the not sure how / when to write the samples decoded.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check the source of my Karaoke Lyrics Editor which is doing exactly what you need based on ffmpeg. See [ffmpegvideoencoder.cpp](https://sourceforge.net/p/karlyriceditor/code/HEAD/tree/src/ffmpegvideoencoder.cpp), see `createFile` and `encodeImage` functions.